# Path integral for the harmonic oscillator

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, path-integral

I would like to check the derivation for the harmonic oscillator in [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/277522/path-integral-approach-to-harmonic-oscillation) using the Gateaux derivative explicitly. (I know that the same result can be achieved using [this](http://www.nyu.edu/classes/tuckerman/stat.mech/lectures/lecture_16/node1.html) but I want to gain practice with the functional derivative.)

So I'm stuck in the computation of

$$
\int dt_1 dt_2 \eta(t_1)\eta(t_2)\frac{\delta^2S[x]}{\delta x(t_1)\delta x(t_2)}|_{x=x_{cl}}.
$$

If $S[x]$ is the classical action, then

$$
\frac{\delta S[x]}{\delta x(t_2)} = -m\frac{d^2x(t_2)}{dt_2^2} - m w^2x(t_2) + J.
$$

For the second functional derivative I get

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\delta^2 S[x]}{\delta x(t_1)\delta x(t_2)} &= \operatorname{lim}_{\epsilon \rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\Big(-m \frac{d^2}{dt^2}(x(t_2) + \epsilon \delta(t_2-t_1)) - mw^2(x(t_2) + \epsilon\delta(t_2-t_1)) + J \\
&+ m\frac{d^2x(t_2)}{dt_2^2} + mw^2x(t_2) - J   \Big)\\
&=\operatorname{lim}_{\epsilon \rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\Big( -m\epsilon\frac{d^2}{dt_2}\delta(t_2-t_1) - \epsilon mw^2\delta(t_2-t_1)  \Big).
\end{split}
$$

If I didn't make a mistake, I'm stuck with the evaluation of

$$
\begin{split}
-m\int dt_1 dt_2 \eta(t_1)\eta_(t_2)\frac{d^2}{dt_2}\delta(t_2-t_1) &= -m\int dt_1  \eta(t_1) \int dt_2\Big(\frac{d}{dt_2}(\eta(t_2)\frac{d}{dt_2}\delta(t_2 - t_1) - \frac{d}{dt_2}\eta(t_2)\times\frac{d}{dt_2}\delta(t_2-t_1)\Big).
\end{split}
$$

The  first term should vanish, since $\eta(t)$ are the quantum fluctuations around the classical path. It is the second term that I cannot justify to be equal to

$$
= m \int dt   \dot{\eta}^2
$$